# Ruby - Remove short words from the string

Tags: ruby

```
string = 'one a day'
```

how do I remove words from the string that are less than 2 characters?

```
result = 'one day'
```

Comment: Come on, man, this is simple! Try a little bit!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Break your string into individual words, filter out short ones, and then glue the string back together.

```
puts 'one a day'.split(' ').select{|w| w.length >= 2}.join(' ')
# => one day
```

Comment: This does not do what the OP asked for because it rejects two-letter words.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Fixed. But he could figure out himself. :-)

Comment: don't need the argument to split() though
`puts 'one a day'.split.select { |w| w.length > 1 }.join(' ')`

Comment: I prefer to be explicit at times. Especially in this case.

Comment: This'd not round-trip perfectly if there were double spaces. That may be a bug, or a feature. (I almost typed "fug"!)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: this wasn't in the spec :-)

Answer (score 1):

This will get rid of 2 or 1 letter words and clean up white space.

`str.gsub(/\b\w{1,2}\b/,"").gsub(/\s{2,}/," ").strip`

Same thing with an array of values.

`str = ["Dave is a dork", "a John is a name", "Shawn is a or Lindsey", "Shawn or Dave"]`

`str.map!  { |str| str.gsub(/\b\w{1,2}\b/,"").gsub(/\s{2,}/," ").strip}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it:

```
string = "on a boat"
result = string.split(' ').reject{|w| w.length < 2 }.join(' ')   # => on boat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"once a day".gsub(/\b\w\b/, "").gsub(/\s+/, "")
# => "once day"
```

Comment: You may just want to add `.gsub("  ", " ")` (two spaces to a single space).

Answer (score 0):

i came independently to the same solution as the best answer, 
so here is a solution considering punctuation

```
string = 'one a day. One 1, 22  333 0. This days o! o'
p string.split(' ').reject{ |e| i = e.dup; i.gsub!(/\W/, ''); i.length == 1}.join(' ')

#==> "one day. One 22 333 This days"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove not only English words, you should use [\p{L}](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties)

```
'Comment ça va ?'.gsub(/\b\p{L}{1,2}\b/, '').squeeze(' ').strip
=> "Coment ?"
```

[Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/MJ0skloxVE)